# Problema al probar sistema en visual fox pro 9 en computadora del cliente

Tags: visual-foxpro

Tengo un sistema en ***visual fox pro 9***, el cual marca error al ser probado en la computadora del cliente.

Ya le instalé archivos ***.ocx*** en su computadora, ***runtime 7 y 9***, ***odbc driver*** para visual fox pro, pero nada me funciona.

[image: archivos .ocx]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los errores que me manda el sistema son los siguientes (ver imagen ),  yo no tengo por ningún lado una base de datos ***bdej1.dbc***.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Realizando un debbuging en el código, me sale un error en la linea siguiente:

```
Evento refresh del textbox rfc

SELECT descripcion,claveregfis FROM regfisc  where personafisica = 1;
        AND eliminado =0;
        Into Cursor csrtamb2
```

En la tabla "**regfisc**", si tengo datos y la consulta , cuando la pruebo si me devuelve información ... sospecho que el error esta en el salto de linea, con punto y coma:

```
AND eliminado = 0;
```

Comment: El fichero bdej1.dbc que el error dice que no encuentra ¿existe?

Comment: Buenas días, ese fichero no existe. lo he buscado en los metadatos del archivo .sct de la pantalla y tampoco esta

Comment: Pues yo investigaría eso, ya que es el error que indica.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así

```
[SELECT descripcion,claveregfis FROM regfisc  where personafisica = 1]+;
        [AND eliminado =0]+;
        [Into Cursor csrtamb2]
```

Ya probaste hacer el query en una sola línea? no es tan grande que digamos.

PD: Tengo 15 años de no tocar Fox y no se si ha cambiado algo en ese tipo de sintaxis.

Comment: no me funciona ya probe, de las 2 maneras que mencionas, gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Buscando información por un problema con MSSOAP, me encontré con esta pregunta. El error es que no encuentra la base de datos a la cual esta ligada la tabla en cuestión. La solución es quitar la liga de la base de datos.
Normalmente se utiliza la base para declarar reglas de negocio. Si no es el caso, dejar la tabla como libre, si no funciona, crear una nueva libre de 0 con los mismos campos e índices, y hacer un append desde la original.